# Visual Studio search results readibility

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there any extension/plugin to categorize search results like in intelliJ IDEA?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVSYv.png

I have found only Entrian Source Search but this is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper used to have an extension(Go to word) that did this.  It was my favorite extension but now it has gone defunct and there does not appear to be anyone willing to pick up the torch and remake this extension: http://screencast.com/t/9qA8nhwY